# How to solve a problem in colored latex table?

Tags: tables, color

I have used the table generator program to generate an academic schedule. The program itself has indicated to me that I should add the `\usepackage[table,xcdraw,usenames]{xcolor}` package in the initial preamble, but still it gives me an error and does not color the table,
Can anyone shed some light?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|cc}
\cline{2-5} \cline{7-7}
                                           & \textbf{LUNES}                                                                     & \textbf{MARTES}                                                                    & \textbf{MIÉRCOLES}                                                                 & \textbf{JUEVES}                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{VIERNES}}                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{8:30-9:25}}   & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}2º ESO B                                                   &                                                                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}2º ESO B                                                   & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8:30-9:25}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{9:25-10:20}}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{6665CD}4º ESO A                                                   &                                                                                    &                                                                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{6665CD}4º ESO A                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9:25-10:20}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{10:20-11:15}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A\end{tabular} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A\end{tabular} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A\end{tabular} &                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10:20-11:15} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH B\end{tabular}}    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{11:15-11:45}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}RECREO}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11:15-11:30} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}RECREO}                                                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{11:45-12:40}} &                                                                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH A\end{tabular}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{6665CD}4º ESO A                                                   &                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11:30-12:25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}2º ESO B}                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{12:40-13:35}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B\end{tabular} &                                                                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH B\end{tabular}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH A\end{tabular}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12:25-13:20} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{13:35-15:00}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}COMIDA}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13:20-14:15} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{15:00-15:55}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH B\end{tabular}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B\end{tabular} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH A\end{tabular}    & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH B\end{tabular}    &                                  &                                                                                                         \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{15:55-16:50}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FyQ\\ 1º BACH A\end{tabular}    &                                                                                    & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B\end{tabular} &                                                                                    &                                  &                                                                                                         \\ \cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Horario seguido durante el período de prácticas.}
\label{tabla:horario seguido}
\end{table}
```

**Preable code**

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{color}
% m\'{a}s modfolortbl} %se necesita para la documentaci\'on de tesis

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ulem}


\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

%
% Añadidos para el TFG d
%
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage[american, cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsbsy} % simbolitos
\usepackage{upgreek} % para poner letras griegas sin cursiva
\usepackage{cancel} % para tachar.
\usepackage{mathdots} % para el comando \iddots
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % para formato de letra
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{arydshln}


\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\pepito}{}


%%%%%%5 itemize
\let\olditemize\itemize
\def\itemize{\olditemize\itemsep=0pt }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\newcounter{ipythcntr}
\newlength\inwd
\setlength\inwd{1.3cm}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{dimgray}{rgb}{0.41, 0.41, 0.41}
\definecolor{aliceblue}{rgb}{0.94, 0.97, 1.0}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}


\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{aliceblue},   
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\tcbset{listing engine=listings}
\newtcblisting{ipythonnb}[1][\theipythcntr]{
  enlarge left by=\inwd,
  width=\linewidth-\inwd,
  enhanced,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=light-gray,
  listing only,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  overlay={
    \node[
      anchor=north east,
      text width=\inwd,
      font=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{blue!50!black},
      inner ysep=2mm,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt
      ] 
      at (frame.north west)
      {\stepcounter{ipythcntr}In [#1]:};
  }
    listing options={
      language=Python,
      basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
      keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
      stringstyle=\color{green},
      commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{red},
      showstringspaces=false,
      columns=fullflexible
  },
}

%
% Definiciones de macros...
%
%

\date{\today}
\textheight = 24.7cm
\textwidth = 15.5cm          %
%\oddsidemargin = -1.2cm    %
\evensidemargin = -0.04cm   %
\topmargin = -1.5cm
\headheight = 0cm 

\newcommand{\com}[1]{
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{**#1 **}}
}
\newcommand{\res}[1]{
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{**#1 **}}
}

\newcommand{\tgr}[1]{
{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
}


\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% Para utilizar Uarial que es un clon de Arial
%% sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a para instalar las fuentes en linux
\ifdefstring{\controlpe}{pe}{
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
}{}

%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of           
%% the document is to be sans 
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%

\input{./ficheros/variables.tex}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definici\'on}[section]
\ifdefstring{\controltp}{ap}{
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand\chaptername{Tema}}
}{}


\newcommand{\documentacion}{si}


\begin{document}
%
% Para cambiar Cuadro por Tabla
%
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0,7mm}
\input{./ficheros/cabecera1.tex}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{0,7mm}

\chapter*{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{0}

\tableofcontents



%% Comienzo de la estructura del tfg
\ifdefstring{\controltp}{tfg}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Capitulos en este espacio %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage\mbox{}


\input{./ficheros/descripcion.tex}
\input{./ficheros/comentario.tex}





\end{document}
```

**Error message**
[image]

Comment: It does compile for me with the preamble `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}` and using `lualatex`.

Comment: Could you please add which error message you get?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Loading the `xcolor` package with the option `table` is supposed to load the `colortbl` package in such a way that maximizes compatibility between `xcolor` and `colortbl`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I did not know that. (But the purpose of the comment above was to provide a working preamble, which it does, even if it has a superfluous line in it.)

Comment: Please tell us more about your TeX distribution (which one? how old) and about any other packages you may be loading. And, please clarify the nature of the error you're encountering. For sure, I encounter no issues if I make your code compilable by prefixing it with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[table,xcdraw,usenames]{xcolor} \begin{document}` and afffixing `\end{document}`.

Comment: Regarding the screenshot of the error message that was recently added: Aparently you are using `\usepackage{xcolor}` AND `\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}` in your premble. To solve this, remove the first one (the one without the options). As a general advice: Please make sure you don't load packges more than once as this can lead to errors, as you observes with your code.

Comment: Yes, two xcolor packages appear, but one is commented. I think the problem comes from the float package

Comment: No it is not related to the `float` package. Please update your question to include the preamble of the document that produces the shown error message.

Comment: Updated with the preamble!!

Comment: The error message can be reproduced with the following minimal example: `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
`. To solve this, place the load `xcolor` before your load `tikz`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some simplifications and improvements to your code. I removed all those unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{c|}`. I also used  `\Centerstack`  from the `stackengine` package in the place of nested tabulars, and loaded the `cellspace` package, which defines a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top of cells in columns with specifier  prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

Unrelated remark: the `usenames` option for `xcolor`has been deprecated for quite a few years, as it is the default now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|*{6}{Sc|}}
\cline{2-5} \cline{7-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{LUNES} & \textbf{MARTES} & \textbf{MIÉRCOLES} & \textbf{JUEVES} & & \textbf{VIERNES} \\ \hline
8:30-9:25 & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}2º ESO B & & \cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}2º ESO B & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A} & 8:30-9:25 & \\ \hline
9:25-10:20 & \cellcolor[HTML]{6665CD}4º ESO A & & & \cellcolor[HTML]{6665CD}4º ESO A & 9:25-10:20 & \\ \hline
10:20-11:15 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH A} & & 10:20-11:15 & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH B} \\ \hline
11:15-11:45 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}RECREO} & 11:15-11:30 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}RECREO \\ \hline
11:45-12:40 & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\Centerstack{FyQ \\ 1º BACH A} & \cellcolor[HTML]{6665CD}4º ESO A & & 11:30-12:25 &\cellcolor[HTML]{9AFF99}2º ESO B \\ \hline
12:40-13:35 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH A} & 12:25-13:20 & \\ \hline
13:35-15:00 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}COMIDA} & 13:20-14:15 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B} \\ \hline
15:00-15:55 & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH A} & \cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH B} \\ \cline{1-5}
15:55-16:50 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCB2F}\Centerstack{FyQ\\ 1º BACH A} & & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFC9E}\Centerstack{FÍSICA\\ 2º BACH B} & \\ \cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Horario seguido durante el período de prácticas.}
\label{tabla:horario seguido}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is how it should look. But I still can't get it.
I have copied your code and made the substitutions that you have indicated, but it does not work.
Could it be because I use the report format instead of article?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Could you post a small code reproducing the problem? ‘Doesn't work’ means what, exactly?

Comment: Preamble is very long, but I add an image with the error message that appears

Comment: This doesn't really address the error. To solve it, `xcolor` with options should be loaded before `tikz` and `tcolorbox`.